# Image as hyperlink in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The ASP.NET GridView control's default column types just don't seem to be up to using an image as a hyperlink.  The HyperLinkField has no image attributes, and the ImageField has no navigation attributes.  Is this possible without using a TemplateField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [HyperLinkField.DataTextFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datatextformatstring.aspx) property with inserting the  tag into this format string

Comment: Nice idea, I'll try it when I'm finished demo'ing, cheating with a TemplateField.